# selenium, xpath: How to select a node within node?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a webpage that have a structure like this:

```
<div class="l_post j_l_post l_post_bright "...>
    ...
    <div class="j_lzl_c_b_a core_reply_content">
       <li class="lzl_single_post j_lzl_s_p first_no_border" ...>
         <div class="lzl_cnt">
         content
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="lzl_single_post j_lzl_s_p first_no_border" ...>
       ...
       </li>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="l_post j_l_post l_post_bright "...>
...(contain content, same as above)
</div>
...
```

Currently I could select all the content in one step like this:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lzl_cnt"]'):
    print(i.text)
```

But as you could see, the webpage consist of repetitive blocks that contain the **contents** that I need, **therefore I want to get those contents separately along with other information that differs between those repetitive blocks(`<div class="l_post j_l_post l_post_bright "...>...</div>`), moreover, I want those contents within `<li class ="lzl_single_post"...>`to be separated so as to be easier for me to process the contents later** . I tried this:

```
items = []

# get each blocks
for sel in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="l_post j_l_post l_post_bright  "]'):
    name = sel.find_element_by_css_selector('.d_name').text
    try: content = sel.find_element_by_css_selector('.j_d_post_content').text
    except: content = '',
    try: 
        reply = []
        # get each post within specific block
        for i in sel.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lzl_cnt"]'):
            reply.append(i.text)
    except: reply = []
    items.append({'name': name, 'content': content, 'reply': reply})
```

But the result shows that I am getting **all the replies on the webpage every time the outer for-loop runs instead of a set of replies for each individual block that I wanted**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.` (context pointer) to XPath as

```
sel.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@class="lzl_cnt"]')
```

Note that `//*[@class="lzl_cnt"]` means *all nodes in DOM with `"lzl_cnt"` class name* while `.//*[@class="lzl_cnt"]` means *all nodes that are descendant of `sel` with `"lzl_cnt"` class name*